# Project Resources variable does not change value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource

I have an xslt file which I initially added to the "Resources" section of my project through the project properties.  Inside of my program I call `Resources.MyXsltFile` to grab the string and I load it using `XslCompiledTransform.Load`.  My program ran fine initially but after I updated the xslt file I noticed that my `Resources.MyXsltFile` was still using the original xslt contents and not my updated version.  What's the deal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the compiled "Resources.Designer.cs" file that goes along with the 'Resources.resx' for the project does NOT get regenerated when you update one of the resource files.  Therefore you have to regenerate the "Resources.Designer.cs" file manually.  Here is an [article](http://chopeen.blogspot.com/2009/05/missing-auto-generated.html) from Marek Grzenkowicz which shows how to regenerate the file by right-clicking on "Resources.resx" and clicking on "Run custom tool".  After that I ran my program and it finally used the updated version of my resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you do not want to use Custom Tool solution, make sure that your resource is using **not at** "No Code Generate" at the **Access Modifier**.

Comment: Where can I configure that?  I see the options "Internal" and "Public" in the "Access Modifier" dropdown on the "Resources" tab for the project properties page but there is no "No code generate".  It is currently set to "Internal".

Comment: Internal is fine, it should generate the Designer file and let you access data from Static methods.